# What are the meaning of template parameters A, B of std::multiset<A,B> respectively, and how does it work?

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

I have asked in another question about **std::multiset**, but now I see I need a decent understanding and cannot find any more complicated example in the internet.

Can you explain to me, maybe exemplarize, how `std::multiset<A,B>` works and what function is here of A and of B, and also if any of those can be omitted? Can I put A or B to some variable?
I'd really appreciate some short example, or reference,

Comment: `std::multiset` is a standard template from recent C++ (notably 2011 standard) libraries. Are you familiar with C++ templates in general? Do you understand `std::vector` and `std::map` already??

Comment: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/multiset.html

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Actually `std::multiset` already existed in C++98, whereas your comment sounds like it is a C++11 feature (or I just misunderstood your comment).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I thought it was only in TR1

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch yes in general I am familiar and I understand those two. But in multiset I don't understand this concept of more than one parameter and I have to deal with it now in some code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) class template has a first template parameter specifying the type of objects to be stored in the set, and a second one specifying the type of a comparison functor. We can ignore the third template parameter for now.

The second, optional, parameter, `B`, must implement [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) and is used to order the set/multiset. This ordering is required to ensure the logarithmic complexity of element look-up operations. Here is an example:

```
struct A
{
  int x;
};

struct B
{
  bool operator()(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) const {
    return lhs.x < rhs.x;
  }
};
```

This class `B` has an `operator()`, which means that it can be called, for example

```
B comp;
A a1, a2;
bool a1lessThana2 = comp(a1, a2);
```

This is needed for the set/multiset to place elements in the correct location, and figure out if two elements are the same. If there is an `operator<` for your type, the second template parameter can be omitted.

```
bool operator<(constA& lhs, const A& rhs) { return lhs.x < rhs.x; }
```

This is an example of usage:

```
int main()
{
  std::multiset<A, B> m;
  A a1, a2;
  a1.x = 23;
  a2.x = 100;
  m.insert(a1);
  m.insert(a2);
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanzaThank you, your great help together with [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) clear it very well! What I still am not sure is: if I put `multiset<A>`, what is the difference in functionality, without `B`? is it worth to know how is `less<>` working with boolean values to sort content of multimap? I mean may this knowledge be needed for some application later on.

Comment: @eco_student `B` is a means to specify the logic you want to use for the ordering, or to specify a logic if there isn't a valid `operator<`. You may have different criteria for ordering elements of a given type, so this gives you the freedom to decide which criterion to use on a per-set/multiset basis.